# Problema de CORS con Axios en proyecto ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, axios

Estoy intentando hacer una petición simple con Axios en un proyecto con React, esta es la petición:

El puerto en el que se ejecuta el proyecto del front es en el 3000. Y el de la API que hace conexión a la base de datos es el 8080.

```
      axios
      .get('http://localhost:8080/api/pregunta')
      .then(function(response) {
        // handle success
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        // always executed
      });
```

La consola de Google Chrome me tira el siguiente error:

> Preguntas.js:243 undefined
>   preguntas:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://localhost:8080/api/pregunta' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Preguntas.js:149 Error: Network Error
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:81)

¿Cómo evito que pase eso si hago las pruebas en localhost?

Intentaba armar una petición personalizada para especificar cosas a la petición, pero no sé cuales son los headers que necesito poner... Este fue mi intento de petición personalizada:

```
const config = {
      url: '/pregunta',
      method: 'get',
      baseURL: 'https://localhost:8080/api/',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
      }
    };
      axios
      .request(config)
      .then(function(response) {
        // handle success
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        // always executed
      });
```

También he intentado con http-proxy-middleware, pero no sé ajustar el proxy de Axios.

Comment: el problema no es axios es tu backend debe permitir el cors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilicé la dependencia `cors`de npm y la apliqué a Express.

```javascript
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

También funciona la extensión de Chrome: [CORS Unblock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-unblock/lfhmikememgdcahcdlaciloancbhjino). Si solo lo necesitas para tus pruebas en `dev`.

Answer (score 1):

Da un vistazo a este paquete: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Lo había utilizado para una aplicación hace un tiempo atrás, es fácil de implementar y se explica muy fácil en la documentación. El módulo genera automáticamente los headers necesarios para que puedas acceder al API sin problema.

Tomado del propietario de la pregunta, Parzival:

```
var cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede ayudar a responder la duda, es mejor editar y añadir las partes escenciales aquí, dejando solo en link como referencia, checa [answer]

Answer (score -1):

Buenas tardes resolví el problema, con las siguientes líneas

```
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```